# Creating DISQUS accounts automatically, when new users register

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, disqus

Using DISQUS, is it possible to create a DISQUS account automatically, when a new user registers on my site? I like DISQUS and everything, but I do not want to make my users register manually for yet another account. I also do not expect them to have an existing one beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SSO which will allows users to sign into a site and fully use Disqus Comments without again authenticating with Disqus

http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/236206-integrating-single-sign-on

Comment: In terms of the user journey: User registers using the site's registration, then they are redirected to Disqus to authenticate the application (site), and then redirect back to site to continue?

Answer (score 0):

1. I am not much familiar with disqus, but most web sites do not provide registration through API to prevent abuse and overuse.
2. If I am not wrong, its not necessary to have an account with disqus, to post the comment. Disqus allows integration with OpenID, google and few other sites.

Comment: still ... it'd be too much to make my users sign in once again